# Nginx error: worker process 12345 exited on signal 6 (core dumped)

Tags: nginx, signals, worker

I habe a problem with nginx. Sometimes, when a user visit my site, the connection are lost, and i don't know why!? The site runs with https:// provided by lets encrypt.

Here the errors:

```
2016/07/21 12:07:07 [alert] 13540#13540: *847 open socket #14 left in connection 16
2016/07/21 12:07:07 [alert] 13540#13540: *942 open socket #32 left in connection 22
2016/07/21 12:07:07 [alert] 13540#13540: aborting
2016/07/21 12:07:07 [alert] 13537#13537: worker process 13539 exited on signal 6 (core dumped)
2016/07/21 12:07:07 [alert] 13537#13537: worker process 13540 exited on signal 6 (core dumped)
```

My nginx version:

> nginx version: nginx/1.10.1
>   built with OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
>   TLS SNI support enabled
>   configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-threads --add-module=/build/nginx-abUnII/nginx-1.10.1/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-module=/build/nginx-abUnII/nginx-1.10.1/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-module=/build/nginx-abUnII/nginx-1.10.1/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-module=/build/nginx-abUnII/nginx-1.10.1/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-module=/build/nginx-abUnII/nginx-1.10.1/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module

ningx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 65535;
debug_points abort;

events {
    worker_connections  4096;
    multi_accept        on;
    use                 epoll;
}
http {
    charset UTF-8;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 10; #65
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;  

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log off;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_static on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript text/x-js;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;

    open_file_cache max=5000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

website.conf:

```
server {
    charset UTF-8;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name website.de;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.de/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.de/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'A value...';
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    #ssl_session_cache none;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript text/x-js;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
}
```

Any ideas, where is the problem? Thanks

Comment: Any luck on figuring this out? Same issue.